# ShareKit plugin not working - Cordova 1.9 & ShareKit 2.0 & ShareKit js plugin & Xcode 4.4

Tags: ios, cordova, phonegap-plugins, sharekit

I have upgraded my Xcode 4.4, Phonegap to Cordova 1.9 and installed the Sharekit 2.0 and I cannot get ShareKit to work.  Prior to upgrading, ShareKit v.021 worked properly -except the known issues with that old version

I installed ShareKit 2.0 as per the [WIKI](https://github.com/ShareKit/ShareKit/wiki/Installing-sharekit). I then updated the ShareKit plugin as per these [**directions**](https://github.com/photokandyStudios/phonegap-plugins/blob/9ba2cbea3dd7a514bf571e2d9d4f15783780d3f3/iOS/ShareKitPlugin/README.md)

My ios app is completely html, css, and js.  I call ShareKit via javascript with the following commands:

> shareToFacebook(msg, url) and shareToTwitter(msg, url)

In the simulator, I get the following error and I have no idea how to fix it.  I inherited this project and I am a newbie, so I am flying a little blind.

**2012-09-21 16:38:29.744 mcs[3976:17603]**  Assertion failure in +[SHK sharersDictionary], /Users/Main/Documents/ShareKit/ShareKit/Classes/ShareKit/Core/SHK.m:528*

****2012-09-21 16:38:29.745 mcs[3976:17603]**  WebKit discarded an uncaught exception in the webView:decidePolicyForNavigationAction:request:frame:decisionListener: delegate:  ShareKit: You do not have properly set sharersPlistName***

I have the defaul SHKSharers.plist in my project with the 9 services still enabled though.  I had only twitter and facebook and I got the same errors.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I finally figured out that my Xcode project did not properly upgrade to the latest phonegap so I rolled back to PhoneGap 1.4 and it is good to go.

Answer (score 0):

In your custom SHKConfigurator file add this:

```
- (NSString*)sharersPlistName {
    return @"SHKSharers.plist";
}
```

SHKSharers.plist is default one comes with ShareKit. You can have one of your own. But make sure you return your plist name in **sharersPlistName** function.